# SQL SUM - ambigous results in multi-join query

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sum

I have this piece of SQL:

```
SELECT 
    PO.[Replan Ref_ No_], 
    PO.[Source No_], 
    ISNULL(SUM(PZ.[Cantitate sudura]), 0) As Sudate, 
    ISNULL(SUM(PZ.[Cantitate montaj]),0) as Montate, 
    ISNULL(SUM(CONVERT(INT, CC.[Cantitate Validata])), 0) as QtyValidata
FROM
    [SC Vermorel SRL$Production Order] AS PO 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [SC Vermorel SRL$ProductieZilnica] AS PZ ON PZ.FPO = PO.[Replan Ref_ No_]
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [SC Vermorel SRL$PregatirePROD] AS PP ON PP.FPO = PO.[Replan Ref_ No_]
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [SC Vermorel SRL$CalitateCTC] as CC ON CC.NrFpo = PO.[Replan Ref_ No_] 
                                        AND CC.[Cod Articol] = PO.[Source No_]
WHERE 
    PO.[Location Code] = 'MACH FIN' 
    AND (PO.Status = 3)
GROUP BY 
    PO.[Replan Ref_ No_], PO.[Source No_]
```

Which returns these results:

[image]

I highlighted in the screen above the result of the `SUM` for the `Cantitate Validata` as `QtyValidata` column for that specific `Replan Ref No_`. The strange thing is that is total non-sense that sum. Bellow you will find a screen with a query and the results from the table in which the `SUM` is done, pointing the fact that for that `Replan Ref No_` the `SUM` should be 1. Not 12. Can someone figure it out what is going on?

[image]

Comment: This is impossible for us to help you with without some test data.  Your `join`s are clearly either not set up correctly or not explicit enough and they are returning multiple records where you are expecting one.  You need to work out which `join` is causing the duplication.

Comment: Oh! Great insight. For sure something like this happens. Thank you, sorry that my question wasn't properly backed by data. I will check it out!

Comment: have you tried removing the GROUP BY then change the SUM to CC.[Cantitate Validata] so that you can check the values that are there

Comment: Think about the carnality of your joins. SQL Server goes from the innermost to outermost join, generally. I would investigate how each of the joins are actually working,so that you can see what the ledt join is really returning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this query is ok for you.

```
SELECT 
    PO.[Replan Ref_ No_], 
    PO.[Source No_], 
    ISNULL(PZA.Sudate, 0) As Sudate, 
    ISNULL(Montate,0) as Montate, 
    ISNULL(CCA.QtyValidata), 0) as QtyValidata
FROM
    [SC Vermorel SRL$Production Order] AS PO 
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT 
        SUM(PZ.[Cantitate sudura]) As Sudate,
        SUM(PZ.[Cantitate montaj]) as Montate,
    FROM [SC Vermorel SRL$ProductieZilnica] AS PZ 
    WHERE PZ.FPO = PO.[Replan Ref_ No_]
    GROUP BY PZ.FPO  -- maybe this group by not need for you
) PZA
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT
        SUM(CONVERT(INT, CC.[Cantitate Validata])) as QtyValidata
    FROM [SC Vermorel SRL$CalitateCTC] as CC
    WHERE CC.NrFpo = PO.[Replan Ref_ No_] 
        AND CC.[Cod Articol] = PO.[Source No_]
    GROUP BY CC.NrFpo, CC.[Cod Articol] -- maybe this group by not need for you
) CCA
WHERE 
    PO.[Location Code] = 'MACH FIN' 
    AND PO.Status = 3
GROUP BY 
    PO.[Replan Ref_ No_], PO.[Source No_]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're somehow duplicating the rows in your join...

To identify the problematic join, run the query without the `group by`, like so...

```
SELECT 
    PO.[Replan Ref_ No_], 
    PO.[Source No_], 
    PZ.[Cantitate sudura] As Sudate, 
    PZ.[Cantitate montaj] as Montate, 
    CONVERT(INT, CC.[Cantitate Validata]) as QtyValidata
FROM
    [SC Vermorel SRL$Production Order] AS PO 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [SC Vermorel SRL$ProductieZilnica] AS PZ ON PZ.FPO = PO.[Replan Ref_ No_]
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [SC Vermorel SRL$PregatirePROD] AS PP ON PP.FPO = PO.[Replan Ref_ No_]
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [SC Vermorel SRL$CalitateCTC] as CC ON CC.NrFpo = PO.[Replan Ref_ No_] 
                                    AND CC.[Cod Articol] = PO.[Source No_]
WHERE 
    PO.[Location Code] = 'MACH FIN' 
    AND (PO.Status = 3)
```